# PHP: trying to create an array from an xdebug output

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to create an array to get this xdebug output:

```
  'user_procedura_list' => 
    array
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
```

But I don't know how..

I have tried:

```
$user_procedura_list[] = array(3,5);
$a['user_procedura_list'] = array(3,5);
```

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$yourVariable['user_procedura_list'] = array(0=>"3", 1=>"5");
var_dump($yourVariable); //expected output
```